# What does $${var} mean?

Tags: bash, for-loop, makefile, pid

What does the `$${spkr}` mean in the following code, which comes from a Makefile?

```
for spkr in $(ALLSPKR); do
    mkdir -p mgc/$${spkr}
    for wav in wav/$${spkr}/$(DATASET)_$${spkr}_*.wav; do
        # other stuff
    done
done
```

Comment: Is it in the context of `make` ?

Comment: Where this code resides? in a make file?

Comment: Yes, is in a make file, thank you everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means you're reading a shell script embedded in a Makefile. The dollar sign is used by `make` for its own variable expansion (e.g. `$(ALLSPKR)` and `$(DATASET)`). Those variables are expanded before the command is run, and the doubled dollar signs become single dollar signs when the command is run, so the shell sees `mkdir -p mgc/${spkr}`

If you really needed the PID in a shell script in a Makefile, you'd have `$$$$`

Answer (score 2):

It's simply a shell variable that's being used inside a Makefile

[Using Variables in Recipes](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Variables-in-Recipes.html)